# How to merger the same values in a table?

Tags: java, loops, spring-boot

I have a data table, this is list object "WorkingTimeReportResponse":

```
WorkingTimeReportResponse(Long lineId, String userName, String projectName, String issue, Float totalHours)
```

the relationship of attributes in object is :

```
(1) userName -> (many) project, 
(1) project -> (many) issue, 
(1) issue -> (1) totalHours.
```

I want to merger the same values of userName and projectName.
My purpose export to excel file. When I report to excel I want to merger it.
I am doing by loop for :

```
for (int i = 0; i < allTasks.size()-1; i++)
```

with "allTasks" is a list object "WorkingTimeReportResponse" and it succeeded, but now I want to loop by:

```
allTasks.stream().forEach(task -> {});
```

Comment: try group operation

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your mean, can you talk detail more?

Answer (score 0):

Group `allTasks` by userName and projectName,the result is a `Map`,key is unique by (userName + projectName),then you can do some reduce operation would you like.

group code like this:

```
    Map<Tuple2<String,String>,List<Response>> groupResult = allTasks.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(workingTimeReportResponse -> new Tuple2<>(workingTimeReportResponse.getUserName(),workingTimeReportResponse.getProjectName())));
```

Tuple2 from vavr library,dependency is,if you don't want to use this library you can create a class:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
    <artifactId>vavr</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```